# Is "markets shares" correct?

Tags: grammatical-number

I know that the common plural form of "market share" (the percentage of a market) is "market shares."
However, I found a sentence containing "markets shares."

> In the last decade, several papers have enriched the theory of the
>   dynamic limit pricing. Kamien and Schwartz (1971), Gaskins (1971), and
>   Baron (1973) have made major contributions. In the Gaskins
>   oligopolistic structural model the dominant firm sets prices. The
>   behavior of the dominant firm allows potential competitors to enter in
>   response to prices, with the outcome depending on the **markets shares**
>   of the dominant firm and its competitors. In Gaskins’ dynamic model, a
>   low-cost dominant firm does not drive out the competing firms in the
>   long run.

from http://www.ams.usda.gov/AMSv1.0/getfile?dDocName=STELPRDC5108810

Is this correct, or wrong?

Comment: One single company has a CEO, a board of directors, a business model, and a market **share**. Two or more companies, taken in the aggregate, have multiple everything, including CEOs, boards of directors, business models, and market **shares**.

Comment: @Robusto Yes. But what about market**s** shares?

Comment: If you have multiple markets and multiple shares of those markets, then I suppose you could have **markets shares**, but that is an odd construction and most people would simply substitute **market shares**.

Comment: I think it's a typo or ignorance. Usda.gov, perfectly capable of both. I once got back at the hick I worked with, the one who hit-counted to resolve all questions, by googling for the "governer" (_sic_) of her state and getting lots of hits, including state sites. Neener neener!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google Ngram chart for the years 1900–2005 indicates that the phrases "market share" (green line), "market shares" (red line), and "markets shares" (blue line) do not have long histories of widespread use:

[image]

Even assuming that the rate of false positives for these three terms is equal (which in the Google Books search results that I examined was not the case, since the false positives for "markets shares" accounted for a much higher percentage of the total matches for "markets shares" than the false positives for either of the other two terms do for their total matches), it is clear that "market share" has been the dominant phrase since 1970, with "market shares" holding steady overall at a considerably lower level for the period 1975–2005, and with "markets shares" flatlining.

Even after taking "market share" out of the mapped results, we're left with no visible uptick for "markets shares" (blue line) when we match that phrase against "market shares" (red line):

[image]

From these results I conclude not simply that "market shares" is the overwhelmingly preferred plural form of "market share," but that "markets shares" has a negligible usage share of the plural "market share" market. So tiny a fraction of total usage suggests either a term with rare practical application (as Robusto suggests in a comment above) or a term that isn't a term at all but a typographical error (as David Pugh suggests in another comment above).